# What collation should I use for amharic language?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, collation

I am using SQL Server 2014. I want to use amharic language in my database. The default collation for the database was `Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. I changed it to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. Both doesn't diplay amharic characters. They show the characters when typing but when comitted they are changed to question marks.

What collation should I use or what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your problem might not be in Collation.

Try to use `UNICODE` data types such as NCHAR and NVARCHAR and you'll see your saved characters.
Collation is only needed for sorting and comparing. Look through the list of collations and choose the most appropriate one.

Originally, you did not tell you are using Full-text search. That requires you to use key word `LANGUAGE` with name of your language. However, there are only 53 supported languages (see in `sys.fulltext_languages`) and `amharic` isn't there.

You have only an option to recreate your Full-text catalog with `the neutral word breaker` and then re-populate it. Then at least it will recognize words by spaces and punctuation marks.
See more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to nvarchar and it worked. But I have these searching and ordering codes which are not working. student.Where(s=>s.name.Contains(str)  and student.OrderBy(s=>s.name) Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Are both sides of your searching parameters in unicode?

Comment: Actually, added more details to my answer. See there.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms143508(v=sql.105).aspx):

> **Default Collations in SQL Server Setup**
>
> In Control Panel, find the Windows system locale name on the Advanced
>   tab in Regional and Language Options. In Windows Vista, use the
>   Formats" tab. The following table shows the corresponding collation
>   designator to match collation settings with an existing Windows
>   locale:

So you have to change the setting using the Control panel so as to see the results.

Comment: I tried to change the locale but amharic is not on the list. There is amharic language and formats and location but not the locale.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search brougth me to [this list of collations, most of them started with SQL Server 2008R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx).

Your collation should be **Latin1_General_100_**

Some more hints:

The SQL Server has a default collation, which is the standard collation for all new databases and - **very important!!!** - the standard collation for your temp-database.

Best would be - if this works for you - to install the SQL Server with the appropriate collation.

SQL Server allows to define a default collation on database level too. But this can lead into deep troubles, if you work with `CREATE TABLE #table` and use `WHERE`,`ORDER BY`,`GROUP BY` or `JOIN` (any comparison...) using character fields...

Last but not least you can define a collation on statement level too. This means a lot ot typing and rather difficult to read code, but offers the best control...

It is a different issue how the output of a query is displayed. This is an issue of the output window (or any other program you are using to display the values of your queries...). In this case it might be necessary to use the appropriate encoding and character set. This depends on the tools you are working with...