# Sql Server filtering not working with Amharic characters

Tags: sql-server

After importing a csv [data set](https://github.com/IsraelAbebe/An-Amharic-News-Text-classification-Dataset/tree/main/data) to sql server I am having problem with filtering.
I used the following query to create the table.

```
create table AmharicNews(
  headline nvarchar(max),
  category nvarchar(400),
  article nvarchar(max)
)
```

I have seen no problem when using `Select * from AmharicNews`.It shows the entire data but when using `WHERE` clause or `DISTINCT` keyword it doesn't work. For example the following queries return wrong data.

```
  select DISTINCT category from AmharicNews
```

It returns the following result which is wrong.

```
category
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ሀገር አቀፍ ዜና

(1 row affected)


Completion time: 2021-12-08T15:05:28.6984198+03:00
```

**Expected result**

```
category
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ሀገር አቀፍ ዜና
መዝናኛ
ስፖርት
ቢዝነስ
ፖለቲካ
ዓለም አቀፍ ዜና

(6 rows affected)


Completion time: 2021-12-08T15:18:30.6179762+03:00
```

And the following returns the entire rows when its expected to return rows whose category equals ስፖርት

```
  select * from AmharicNews WHERE category = N'ስፖርት' --ስፖርት is Sport equivalent of Amharic
```

Not just the above queries but everything containing `WHERE` clause doesn't work. This includes `update`statements affecting the entire rows.

I am using SQL Server 2019

Comment: What collation are you using?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700328/what-collation-should-i-use-for-amharic-language

Comment: I have check that before asking but it didn't help me.

Comment: I am using THE DEFAULT ```SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS```

Comment: @lptr: Your dbfiddle is pretty unclear about what a _100_ collation does solve, see my additions to your dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc783f450b929a21198e0c7f9094ceeb

Comment: ok, a second look, and some edits made the dbfiddle more clear (to me): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ed1e66b53754524b669526aaaff9559

Comment: Thank you both now its working I updated the columns collation instead of using the ```collate```  keyword in query. please add it to answer so that I can vote for it.  i used this query to update the columns collation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I used this query from MSDN                                                                                    
       ```ALTER TABLE dbo.AmharicNews --Latin1_General_100_CI_AI 
ALTER COLUMN article nVARCHAR(max) COLLATE  Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8``` In both collations it works the same way. One thing that should not be forgotten when querying is to use the ```N``` prefix in where clauses ex ```where category = N'unicode value' ```